# Get corresponding point using essential matrix

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Using feature extractors and descriptors, I have calculated the essential matrix `E`,between two views (images). Since I have the camera intrinsics `K`, I can obtain the fundamental matrix `F` as well.

Given an image coordinate `(x,y)`, can I obtain the `(x', y')` coordinates of the point in the second view. If so, how does one do that?

Going through literature, it seems that I can obtain the epipolar line and not the exact point, but I am not entirely sure. If I can obtain the depth of the `(x,y)` coordinate, i.e. I get the 3D location of the coordinate, can I solve the problem?

One obvious solution is to find `R` and `t` from the essential matrix, transform the 3D point and reproject it onto the new image. But in a monocular setting, the translation is always of unit length, hence the scale is ambiguous, which may not help. Thus, what is the best way to obtain the solution while staying in the image space itself, i.e. using `E` and `F` alone?

Sample:

```
E = np.asarray([-5.87054215e-04, -6.95705527e-01, -1.25874334e-01],
 [ 6.95659154e-01, -6.83523163e-04,  1.27646362e-02],
 [ 1.26062967e-01, -1.23362647e-02,  1.03722270e-04]])
K = np.array([[1.06682307e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 6.14908333e+02], [0.00000000e+00 ,1.06935269e+03 ,3.28409838e+02], [0.00000000e+00 ,0.00000000e+00 ,1.00000000e+00]])

pt1 = [140,400]
```

Suppose depth of `pt1` is `6.2`.
How do I find pt2, i.e. coordinates of pt1 in view2.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you cannot.

Long answer: you need to solve for 3d structure and motion, using the image space as the place where the evidence for both is validated. You are obviously in a calibrated scenario, so you may want to look for either stereo reconstruction or, if in a multi-view scenario, for bundle adjustment.